# Are objective-c objects all same type of C-structure?

Tags: objective-c, runtime

I want to know how the language's object-oriented features are implemented in C.

As defined in `<objc/runtime.h>`, `id` type is a pointer to a `objc_object`, and `objc_object` type is a C-structure with only one member `isa` storing a `Class`. Then where and how are the actual values of any object's instance-variables stored?

One more thing, the fact that all objective-C object-pointers can be casted to `id` (which is a pointer to a C-structure, where no feature such as inheritance exists), are Objective-C classes just qualifiers for the compiler, and all instances equally type of `objc_object`?

**added:**

```
NSObject *obj = [NSObject new];
objc_object *objStruct = (__bridge objc_object *)obj;
NSLog(@"obj: %@", NSStringFromClass(objStruct->isa));

NSString *str = [NSString new];
objc_object *strStruct = (__bridge objc_object *)str;
NSLog(@"str: %@", NSStringFromClass(strStruct->isa));
```

This code compiles and outputs:

```
obj: NSObject, str: __NSCFConstantString
```

Both `obj` and `str` can be casted to `objc_object *`, which means both variables are pointers of a same type, no?

**resolved**

Understood! I was misunderstanding how pointer-casting works. `obj` and `str` are pointers of different structure-types, but both commonly have Class-type member `isa` at the front of the memory, so can be treated as a `objc_object`. The code below mimics this mechanism:

```
typedef struct {
    int isa;
} Fake_NSObject;

typedef struct {
    int isa;
    char *string;
} Fake_NSString;

Fake_NSObject obj = {1};
Fake_NSObject *objPtr = &obj;
NSLog(@"obj: %d", objPtr->isa); // prints 1

Fake_NSString str = {2, "abc"};
Fake_NSString *strPtr = &str;
NSLog(@"str: %d", strPtr->isa); // prints 2

Fake_NSObject *objPtr2 = (Fake_NSObject *)strPtr; // this is ok.
NSLog(@"obj2: %d", objPtr2->isa); // prints 2

Fake_NSString *strPtr2 = (Fake_NSString *)objPtr; // this is invalid, but still works.
NSLog(@"str2: %d", strPtr2->isa); // prints 1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Then where and how are the actual values of it's instance-variables stored?

They're stored in the same place as always -- inside the object. As you say, `id` represents a pointer to any kind of object. However, it doesn't define any specific type beyond that -- it doesn't say anything about the *actual* type of the object.

`objc_object` is just a base type that's equivalent to `NSObject`. Take a look at NSObject.h and you'll see that an instance of `NSObject` has a single instance variable, the `isa` pointer. The same is true for `NSProxy`, which is another root class in Objective-C. Subclasses of `NSObject` or `NSProxy` can add their own instance variables, which are appended to the parent's structure.

> if all objective-C object-pointers can be casted to
>   id, are all Objective-C classes just qualifiers for the compiler, and
>   at runtime all those instances equally type of objc_object?

I'm not sure what you're asking here. The compiler won't stop you from sending any message to any object (although it will warn you if it thinks you're sending a message to an object that doesn't support it), so in a sense the compiler doesn't care about the various object types. On the other hand, objects of different types *are* different -- there's not universal type that all classes are converted to.

`id` is strongly analogous to `void *`. `void *` is a generic pointer, and you can cast any pointer to `void *`, but that doesn't mean that all pointers are equivalent. `id` is pretty much the same thing with the added restriction that the pointer you assign to a variable of type `id` has to point to an Objective-C object.

Comment: `id` is clearly different from `void *` in that it is actually *defined* as a pointer to a C-structure, and if any variable is able to cast to that type, that means that variable must be a type of it too, no?

Comment: @TaketoSano Objects are just structs with a sense of being.  "Inside the object" means that the ivars are a part of (literally) the structure of the object itself.  You can even make a C++ class an ObjC Object by deriving it from `objc_object` and setting its `isa` to a valid class.  In the context of the language, `id` means "I can possibly respond to any message", not "I can fill in for any type." (that's just a side effect of it's implementation)

Comment: Then and how can they be casted to a 'base' structure that has less number of members and size?

Comment: @TaketoSano They can be cast in the same way that I can cast any given object to `void*` or `uintptr_t` and back.  A cast is a promise to the compiler, and if you decide to "Slice" away information from the type, that's your problem

Comment: @TaketoSano isa is usually of type `Class`, but other than that, that's the [gist of it](https://gist.github.com/iamleeg/5540103).  It's amazing to find out how much of Apple's "magic" is just a thick layer of glue over C.

Comment: I see... there was a misunderstanding in casting pointers. I wrote a code above that's supposed to mimic what's going on inside the runtime. Am I getting it right? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @TaketoSano That's what it boils down to (of course, the Runtime is quite a bit more complicated than that, but for all intents and purposes.)

Comment: @TaketoSano You seem to have drunk too much C++. C has **no type safety at all.** -- "Both obj and str can be casted to a pointer to a objc_object, which means both variables are pointers of a same type, no?" - No. In C, almost anything can be cast to almost anything. Consider `float pi = 3.14; uint32_t i = *(uint32_t *)&pi; id bogusPtr = (id)i;`