# -(void) setOrigin:(XYPoint *) pt

Tags: xcode4.5

I may be wrong but if I would translate this I would come up with this:

An instance method with no value returned, with a method name setOrigin which will take a pointer to an argument named pt of the class XYPoint.

Now, what the hell did I just wrote down. Please explain. Tyvm.

Comment: Thx. So if XYPoint is a class (@class XYPoint) and not a descendant of NSObject the explanation lies in your first sentence. The (XYPoint *) refers in this case to an XYPoint structure that has the same name as the class XYPoint but is not the actual class XYPoint. The XYPoint struct has the same characteristics provided by the class XYPoint? Or am I confusing everything? Thx.

Comment: Look at it this way: if you define T as an Obj-C class (@class T), then instances of T are represented by T *. But you should not treat T * as a regular C pointer (i.e. you should not dereference it). Treat it as a reference to your object, which happens to share the syntax with C pointers, and you should not be bothered how Objective-C represents it internally. (If you are interested in Objective-C internals, have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783557/are-objective-c-objects-all-same-type-of-c-structure )

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context.

If XYPoint is a C-struct, then you'd interpret it as an instance method, which takes a pointer to (aka the address of) an XYPoint struct, possibly for returning some value by reference.

If XYPoint is a descendant of NSObject, then you'd rather say: it's an instance method, which takes an XYPoint *object*. Descendants of NSObject are reference-counted objects, and passed around via pointers (although I would call them *references* to emphasise that they're not regular pointers to C types).

Comment: Thx. So if XYPoint is a class (@class XYPoint) and not a descendant of NSObject the explanation lies in your first sentence.

Comment: I think I got it now. Still a bit confusing though. Anyhow, tyvm.